# Using Identity server 4 only for Oauth2 authorization without OpenID Connect scope - is it possible?

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect

Is it possible to get oauth2 requests without OpenID scope? It appears that it is mandatory to have OpenID as a scope, however I just need to achieve to issue access tokens with oauth2 flow without ID tokens.

Is it possible to generate requests in such a way that no OpenID scope is included?

Comment: Identity Server is exactly for OIDC, why do you want to use it if you only want OAuth?

Comment: You can always ignore the ID token if it is not needed. Why do you not want the openid scope?

Comment: Thanks for reply, we have already set it up and it appears we should also respond to requests which will not have openid scope in it.   due to requirements  it was necessary to have oauth2 authorization flow,  with possibility to use OpenID in the future, now it appears that if no openid scope is present in request  we are receiving scope errors.  if there is some way to avoid mandatory request for openid scope  that would be great

Comment: service is such that, requests from third parties are formed in a way that only consent authorization is needed,  without need of sharing identity  info(so no profile emai etc). and as identityserver 4 requires to have openid scope as mandatory requests are getting error - invalid scope (as they do not have openid scope in their requests). so we are searching for possibility to change something in identityserver4 which would allow us to use it just for authorization (oauth2 ) and not for authentication (OIDC) - so without openid scope. so far we were unable to find such a possibility :(

Answer (score 0):

`openid` scope is [mandated by the OIDC spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#rfc.section.2.1.1.1) when executing an authorization flow. `openid` scope requests `sub` claim, which is populated with the user identifier when the user signs in.

If you don't need the user info, you might be better off using **client credentials** grant type. Or, if you really do want to use authorization code grant type without `openid` scope, you'll have to override the request validation and build your own custom grant type.

Answer (score 0):

OpenId Connect is a layer built on the OAuth2 protocol, so technically it is an OAuth2 service.

Your client requests must be OAuth2:

- They can only use 'code' or 'token' response types and they cannot use multiple response types.
- The required scopes must be only from Api Resources, not from Identity Resources and the scope 'openid' cannot be requested.
- At least one scope must be requested.
- The scopes must exist and must be related with a resource (Api Resource).
- You can get an 'invalid scope' error too if you use a too long scope name (>300 characters).